# Functional Hessian of the Palatini action

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, variational-calculus, functional-derivatives

Let's write the Palatini action like the following:
\begin{align*}
S_P&=\int \epsilon^{\alpha \beta \gamma \delta}\epsilon_{IJKL}e^I_\alpha e^J_\beta\Omega^{KL}_{\gamma \delta}
\\
&=\int \epsilon^{\alpha \beta \gamma \delta}\epsilon_{IJKL}e^I_\alpha e^J_\beta\delta^{\kappa \lambda}_{\gamma \delta}\nabla_\kappa \omega_\lambda^{KL}
\end{align*}
Where $$\Omega=d_\omega\omega=d\omega+\omega\wedge \omega$$, $\delta^{\kappa \lambda}_{\gamma \delta}$ is the generalized Kronecker delta, and $\nabla$ is the covariant derivative expressed with $\omega$ only. Does the following functional hessian vanish?
\begin{equation*}
\frac{\delta^2 S_P}{\delta \omega_\mu^{IJ}(x) \delta \omega_\nu^{KL}(y)}\stackrel{?}{=}0
\end{equation*}
The covariant derivative depends on $\omega$ but since it is an operator and not a function on $\omega$ I don't know if I have to take these contributions into account.